# How to Handle NoSuchElementException for empty element.and still execute next line of code?

Tags: java, selenium, nosuchelementexception

i am trying to get text of dynamic web table to excel sheet , sometimes text is present in rows of column and sometime it is not.. when text is present  in the table row , i want to get text of that cell..using getText Method, But when Text is not present i want to write empty text and keep cell blank.. But it is giving NoSuchElementException.. how to handle that..?? any help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance..

```
    String actualXpath_SL = beforeXpath_SL + j + afterXpath_SL;
    String SL = driver.findElements(By.xpath(actualXpath_SL)).getText()

    currentRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(SL);
```

Comment: @supputuri  hi can you help me with this

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: @SAhmed unable to get Text  getText Method.. when element is not present..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue your programme when selenium doesn't find an element you can do two things.

- Put the code inside a try block and handle the `NoSuchElementException` in the catch block.

```java
String OneA = "";
try{
    //find element
    OneA = driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualXpath_1A)).getText();
}catch (NoSuchElementException e){
    //stacktrace and other code after catching the exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Or**, you can use `findElements` and check the returned list is empty or not.

```
List<WebElement> elements  = driver.findElements(By.xpath(actualXpath_1A));
String OneA = "";
if(!elements.isEmpty()){
    OneA = elements.get(0).getText();
} else {
    //Handle if no element present
}
```

the second solution avoids the exception and it is faster than waiting for the exception.

Comment: how do i access OneA var in out of the block i.e in setCellValue

Comment: Declare the String outside the scope of try block or the if block.

Comment: I've edited the code with the string declared outside. Try it out.

Comment: @S Ahmed hi i have tried what you say..but not working..please have a look at edited question

Comment: Which part is not working? It prints all the elements I think, like this`AA 55063 STP DAL PASS STP DAL 14:42 14:44 00:02H Y Y Y Y Y Y Y UNRESERVED TRAIN`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.size()>0` rather `isEmpty()`

```
String actualXpath_2S = beforeXpath_2S + j + afterXpath_2S;
List<WebElement> eight = driver.findElements(By.xpath(actualXpath_2S));
String TwoS="";
if(eight.size()>0){
    TwoS = eight.get(0).getText();
}
```

You have to update the logic for all if conditions that are using `isEmpty`.

Comment: If you have to access the variables like `TwoS` then declare them as class variables.

Comment: I think you should be good with the issue that mentioned in the Original post. If you need any further clarification on the variable usage please mention it in another question. Don't want to get someone get confused with multiple issues in the same post.

Comment: Getting some output on console..which is very slow..and not feasible.. after first rows..and on browser not showing any action performing.. after first click..